# Merge identical queries but with different conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 queries like this:

```
select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%') as "Summ",
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%' and completed is true) as "Summ completed"
 from archived_order where created_user_login like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
 and created between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date;
```

```
select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2570%') as "Summ",
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2570%' and completed is true) as "Sum completed"
 from archived_order where created_user_login not like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
 and data like '%"cci":3%' 
 and created between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date;
```

Their difference are in the data conditions. I need to get these 2 queries as one with separated output from each other, and add much more queries in it, but with different data conditionals.

Data conditional will be from `'%"pmi":2568%'` and `'%"cci":1%'` to `'%"pmi":2570%'` and `'%"cci":6%'`

For each `pmi` - `cci` should be going from 1 to 6.

I've tried WITH and UNION but not sure how it works, and the output told me that i don't know how to make it.

This query is going to be used to create a report in html, so count should be able to write in html file.

Comment: *and the output told me that* What is wrong with the output? UNION must solve your task...

Comment: @Akina UNION should, but i can't make it right. SO i'm asking for help.

Comment: Copy 1st query text, remove trailing `;`, add `UNION ALL` wrapped with spaces, add 2nd query text. That's all. The only problem I see is how to distinguist what subquery each separate record is taken from...

Comment: @Akina it's one of the main problems, because it's going to be used in report - so it should be named somehow.

Comment: @Akina Can we make an empty column just to declare what is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need in something like

```
select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%') as "Summ",
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmn":"CHILD_SEAT"%' and completed is true) as "Summ completed",
       'subquery-1' "what subquery is a source"
from archived_order 
where created_user_login like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date

UNION ALL

select count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2570%'),
       count(id) filter (where data like '%"pmi":2570%' and completed is true),
       'subquery-2'
from archived_order 
where created_user_login not like 'exchangeAgent@shara' 
  and data like '%"cci":3%' 
  and created between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date;
```

?

Of course the identifying literals may be any. Including numbers.